# Cannot import name 'CRS' from 'pyproj' for using the osmnx library

Tags: python, anaconda, data-science, osmnx, pyproj

I have used a fresh anaconda install to download and install all the required modules for osnmx library but I got the following error:
[image]

Comment: Please don’t share information as an image unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: What version of pyproj do you have installed? You need 2+.

Comment: See some hints here, https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/400 I thought it is over now, with conda and stuff, you do not need to collect wheels, eggs, over various servers, and you have it all in powershell as easy as on Mac/Unix. NO. After 2 yeras with mac i needed to install on windows server.... 2 days of various bugs, including adding to PATH, installing C++ from Visual Studio, compiling C and stuff... dude, I hoped those times were gone.

Answer (score 11):

I am the developer of OSMnx. There is a growing amount of misinformation and confusion in this thread, so I will give you a definitive answer.

**Just follow the documented [installation instructions](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#installation)** to install the latest release of OSMnx:

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx
```

If you install an old version of pyproj + a new version of OSMnx, or an old version of OSMnx + a new version of pyproj, you will get package conflicts such as the `ImportError` above. The same problems can crop up if you just conda install it or pip install it without following the documented installation instructions. Required dependency versions can be seen [here](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/master/requirements.txt). Make sure you have 64-bit python (anaconda/miniconda) installed. OSMnx is pure Python and thus its installation alone is trivial, *but*, it depends on geopandas which itself has tricky dependencies to install. If you follow the documented installation instructions, it should all be smooth and seamless.

To summarize:

- **do** just follow the simple [installation instructions](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#installation) in the OSMnx documentation
- **don't** just run `conda install osmnx`
- **don't** just run `pip install osmnx`
- **don't** run `pip install -U pyproj psutil`
- **don't** use pip at all unless you have already installed all of OSMnx's dependencies and confirmed they are all working properly (note: this is nontrivial)

If you follow the installation instructions in the documentation and still have trouble, please report what you did **step by step with full details at the [feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/osmnx-feedstock/issues)** so we can reproduce it and quickly fix it!

Again, the [installation instructions](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#installation) are in the documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems using environments on Windows no longer works: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10025

Comment: Using conda environments on windows continues to work just fine. If you're experiencing an installation problem with it, please open an issue at the OSMnx conda-forge repo, so we can reproduce and troubleshoot it.

Comment: Today the environment I created works. It is possible that you need to restart your PC after installing?

Answer (score 6):

I have had the same issue and turned out that it did not like the latest release of osmnx (0.11.3). It could be that that version is unstable as its new (9th January 2020).

I have sort out the issue by uninstalling the osmnx 0.11.3

```
conda uninstall osmnx
```

and forcing to install the osmnx 0.11 version

```
pip install osmnx==0.11
```

Comment: Did not work for me, pip cannot install osmnx , keeps on hiting some bugs, thw only way to install osmnx on widnows seem to be from conda, yet now there is this error.
I spent 2nd day installing osmnx on windows..... cool!

Comment: This is not the correct answer. I am the package developer. I have provided a detailed answer below, including where to go if you follow the documented installation instructions and still get an error. The installation should be simple and straightforward if you follow my instructions.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I had trouble with installing this too (and am completely new to Python). The most recent MacOSX download of anaconda (2020.11) contained version 2.3 (I think it was) of networkx and I saw that this does not satisfy the required dependency listed. Anyway, having installed the networkx to 2.5 it now works swimmingly. Thanks for the package!

Comment: Is this an answer or a "Thank you"?

Answer (score 0):

I tried all solutions, but nothing worked with me. Then, I tried this line below and everything worked:

```
pip install -U pyproj psutil
```