# Getting TypeError: argument of type 'CRS' is not iterable with OSMnx Package

Tags: python, geopandas, osmnx

This question [appears to have been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60312055/python-getting-typeerror-argument-of-type-crs-is-not-iterable-with-osmnx), but none of the answers helped in my case. First I should say that I've followed the [OSMnx Installation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#installation) steps exactly. Then tried to run the following code in a Jupyter Notebook:

```
place = "San Francisco, California, USA"
g = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type="bike")
```

After trying this simple code, the following error message was returned:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d7dc3d6ea906> in <module>()
      1 #Get Bay Area Bike Network
      2 place = "San Francisco, California, USA"
----> 3 g = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type="bike")

/Users/jcroff/anaconda3/envs/ox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osmnx/core.py in graph_from_place(query, network_type, simplify, retain_all, truncate_by_edge, name, which_result, buffer_dist, timeout, memory, max_query_area_size, clean_periphery, infrastructure)
   1809                            name=name, timeout=timeout, memory=memory,
   1810                            max_query_area_size=max_query_area_size,
-> 1811                            clean_periphery=clean_periphery, infrastructure=infrastructure)
   1812 
   1813     log('graph_from_place() returning graph with {:,} nodes and {:,} edges'.format(len(list(G.nodes())), len(list(G.edges()))))

/Users/jcroff/anaconda3/envs/ox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osmnx/core.py in graph_from_polygon(polygon, network_type, simplify, retain_all, truncate_by_edge, name, timeout, memory, max_query_area_size, clean_periphery, infrastructure)
   1678         # create a new buffered polygon 0.5km around the desired one
   1679         buffer_dist = 500
-> 1680         polygon_utm, crs_utm = project_geometry(geometry=polygon)
   1681         polygon_proj_buff = polygon_utm.buffer(buffer_dist)
   1682         polygon_buffered, _ = project_geometry(geometry=polygon_proj_buff, crs=crs_utm, to_latlong=True)

/Users/jcroff/anaconda3/envs/ox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osmnx/projection.py in project_geometry(geometry, crs, to_crs, to_latlong)
     51     gdf['geometry'] = None
     52     gdf.loc[0, 'geometry'] = geometry
---> 53     gdf_proj = project_gdf(gdf, to_crs=to_crs, to_latlong=to_latlong)
     54     geometry_proj = gdf_proj['geometry'].iloc[0]
     55     return geometry_proj, gdf_proj.crs

/Users/jcroff/anaconda3/envs/ox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osmnx/projection.py in project_gdf(gdf, to_crs, to_latlong)
    100             # else, project the gdf to UTM
    101             # if GeoDataFrame is already in UTM, just return it
--> 102             if (gdf.crs is not None) and ('proj' in gdf.crs) and (gdf.crs['proj'] == 'utm'):
    103                 return gdf
    104 

TypeError: argument of type 'CRS' is not iterable
```

For reference, here are the packages is my conda environment:

```
# packages in environment at /Users/jcroff/anaconda3/envs/ox:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
appnope                   0.1.2            py36h79c6626_1    conda-forge
argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py36h20b66c6_2    conda-forge
async_generator           1.10                       py_0    conda-forge
attrs                     21.2.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
bleach                    3.3.0              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
boost-cpp                 1.74.0               h43a636a_2    conda-forge
branca                    0.4.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py36h20b66c6_1001    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h0d85af4_4    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.17.1               h0d85af4_1    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2020.12.5            h033912b_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.16.0            he43a7df_1008    conda-forge
certifi                   2020.12.5        py36h79c6626_1    conda-forge
cffi                      1.14.5           py36hfaecaff_0    conda-forge
cfitsio                   3.470                h01dc385_7    conda-forge
chardet                   4.0.0            py36h79c6626_1    conda-forge
click                     7.1.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
click-plugins             1.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
cligj                     0.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cryptography              3.4.7            py36h3d45be8_0    conda-forge
curl                      7.76.1               h06286d4_1    conda-forge
cycler                    0.10.0                     py_2    conda-forge
decorator                 5.0.7              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
descartes                 1.1.0                      py_4    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.3             pyhd8ed1ab_1003    conda-forge
expat                     2.3.0                he49afe7_0    conda-forge
fiona                     1.8.19           py36hba155ba_0    conda-forge
folium                    0.12.0             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.13.1            h10f422b_1005    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               h4cff582_1    conda-forge
freexl                    1.0.6                h0d85af4_0    conda-forge
gdal                      3.2.2            py36h99bc8e5_3    conda-forge
geographiclib             1.50                       py_0    conda-forge
geopandas                 0.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
geopy                     2.1.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
geos                      3.9.1                he49afe7_2    conda-forge
geotiff                   1.6.0                hba2ba3e_5    conda-forge
gettext                   0.19.8.1          h7937167_1005    conda-forge
giflib                    5.2.1                hbcb3906_2    conda-forge
hdf4                      4.2.13            hefd3b78_1005    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.6          nompi_hc5d9132_1114    conda-forge
icu                       68.1                 h74dc148_0    conda-forge
idna                      2.10               pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        4.0.1            py36h79c6626_0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 5.5.4            py36h495a4c6_0    conda-forge
ipython                   5.8.0                    py36_1    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.11.3             pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9d                   hbcb3906_0    conda-forge
json-c                    0.15                 hcb556a6_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_3    conda-forge
jupyter_client            6.1.12             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.7.1            py36h79c6626_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
kealib                    1.4.14               h31dd65d_2    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.3.1            py36h615c93b_1    conda-forge
krb5                      1.17.2               h60d9502_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0                9_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0                9_openblas    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.76.1               h8ef9fac_1    conda-forge
libcxx                    11.1.0               habf9029_0    conda-forge
libdap4                   3.20.6               h3e144a0_2    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         h0678c8f_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 haf1e3a3_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.3                  h046ec9c_2    conda-forge
libgdal                   3.2.2                h9a52621_3    conda-forge
libgfortran               5.0.0           9_3_0_h6c81a4c_22    conda-forge
libgfortran5              9.3.0               h6c81a4c_22    conda-forge
libglib                   2.68.2               hd556434_0    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.16                 haf1e3a3_0    conda-forge
libkml                    1.3.0             h8fd9edb_1013    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0                9_openblas    conda-forge
libnetcdf                 4.8.0           nompi_h81fa352_101    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.43.0               h07e645a_0    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.15          openmp_h5e1b9a4_0    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h7cec526_2    conda-forge
libpq                     13.2                 h052a64a_2    conda-forge
librttopo                 1.1.0                h5413771_6    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               hbcb3906_1    conda-forge
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h1c7c35f_3    conda-forge
libspatialite             5.0.1                heb715ac_4    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.9.0                h52ee1ee_6    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.2.0                h7c11950_1    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.2.0                h0d85af4_2    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.10               h93ec3fd_4    conda-forge
libzip                    1.7.3                hbc046b2_0    conda-forge
llvm-openmp               11.1.0               hda6cdc1_1    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h046ec9c_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                1.1.1            py36h20b66c6_3    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.2.2                         1    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.2.2            py36h83d3ec1_1    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py36h20b66c6_1003    conda-forge
munch                     2.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
nbclient                  0.5.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 6.0.7            py36h79c6626_3    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.2                  h2e338ed_4    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.5.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
networkx                  2.3                        py_0    conda-forge
notebook                  6.3.0            py36h79c6626_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.19.5           py36h08dc641_1    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.4.0                h6cbf5cd_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1k               h0d85af4_0    conda-forge
osmnx                     0.7.3                    py36_0    conda-forge
packaging                 20.9               pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
pandas                    1.1.5            py36h2be6da3_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    2.13                 h0d85af4_0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
pcre                      8.44                 hb1e8313_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pip                       21.1.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pixman                    0.40.0               hbcb3906_0    conda-forge
poppler                   21.03.0              h640f9a4_0    conda-forge
poppler-data              0.4.10                        0    conda-forge
postgresql                13.2                 ha63e576_2    conda-forge
proj                      8.0.0                h1512c50_0    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.10.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            1.0.15                     py_1    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.20               pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pygments                  2.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 20.0.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
pyproj                    3.0.1            py36hc662631_1    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.17.3           py36h20b66c6_2    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py36h79c6626_3    conda-forge
python                    3.6.13          h7728216_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.6                     1_cp36m    conda-forge
pytz                      2021.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyzmq                     22.0.3           py36h50cd92c_1    conda-forge
readline                  8.1                  h05e3726_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.25.1             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
rtree                     0.9.7            py36h49c2f37_1    conda-forge
send2trash                1.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
setuptools                49.6.0           py36h79c6626_3    conda-forge
shapely                   1.7.1            py36h7f0d9e5_4    conda-forge
simplegeneric             0.8.1                      py_1    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.35.5               h44b9ce1_0    conda-forge
terminado                 0.9.4            py36h79c6626_0    conda-forge
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0    conda-forge
tiledb                    2.2.9                he9a4fb4_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.10               h0419947_1    conda-forge
tornado                   6.1              py36h20b66c6_1    conda-forge
traitlets                 4.3.3            py36h9f0ad1d_1    conda-forge
typing_extensions         3.7.4.3                    py_0    conda-forge
tzcode                    2021a                h0d85af4_1    conda-forge
tzdata                    2021a                he74cb21_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.4             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
xerces-c                  3.2.3                h379762d_2    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                haf1e3a3_1    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.4                h1c7c35f_0    conda-forge
zipp                      3.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h7795811_1010    conda-forge
zstd                      1.4.9                h582d3a0_0    conda-forge
```

In reviewing the answers from the question mentioned above, looks like the developer does not support reverting back to an older version of geopandas, as the past couple of releases require `geopandas>=0.7`. Any help in resolving this issue would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: What version of pyproj are you using? Can you run `conda list` in the environment in which you installed OSMnx then add its output to your question?

Comment: @gboeing I've added the packages installed in my env to my question above. I'm using pyproj version 3.0.1. Thanks for getting back to me so quickly!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have installed an extremely old version of OSMnx. Your `conda list` output shows you have version 0.7.3 installed, and that was released 3 or 4 years ago. It's so old that it's incompatible with the modern features of GeoPandas and pyproj, including the modern CRS object that's causing your error. I'm not clear how you did it! My best guess is you installed using one of the old tags on this [page](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/osmnx), which do point to version 0.7.3.

This should be fixed by removing the old environment and then following the installation instructions [here](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/), like:

```
conda env remove -n ox
conda clean --all --yes
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm not sure how it happened either. I actually followed the steps on this [page](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#installation) exactly and I actually removed the environment and recreated the environment from the steps on the aforementioned page. I also double checked my version of conda to see if that had something to do with it and I'm at 4.10.1. I'll try again right now with the above steps and see if I install the correct version this time. :)