# How to install libspatialindex to enable Rtree in windows?

Tags: osmnx, r-tree, libspatialindex

While installing `libspatialindex` using `pip` in Windows I am getting the below error

Command:

```
python -m pip install libspatialindex
```

Error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libspatialindex (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for libspatialindex
```

Actually, I want to install osmnx which depends on Rtree and the Rtree depends on libspatialindex.
How can I solve this error? Anyone please help me. Thank you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62958055/7321942

Comment: Not yet solved..

Comment: You tagged this question `osmnx`. Are you trying to install rtree as a dependency for OSMnx? If so, the linked SO answer above explains how.