# How to install osmnx in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am trying to use osm library in Python. I found a recommended package called osmnx. I installed it via the command:

```
python -m pip install osmnx
```

when I type:

```
py -m pip freeze
```

I receive:

```
click==7.1.2
cycler==0.10.0
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Ext==0.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
kiwisolver==1.3.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.3.4
numpy==1.20.1
osm==1.4
overpy==0.4
Pillow==8.1.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
six==1.15.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.23
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

but osmnx is never there. Consequently when I run the code posted below, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m:\python lessons\flask apps\osm\osmnx\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import osmnx as ox
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osmnx'
```

Please let me know how to install osmnx in Python.
**code**:

```
import osmnx as ox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

place_name = "Kamppi, Helsinki, Finland"
graph = ox.graph_from_place(place_name)
```

Comment: Did you read the OSMnx documentation? It provides specific installation instructions. https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ Question may be a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/62958055/7321942

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm using OSMX inside of Blender which comes with its own Python distribution and Blender doesn't work well with Conda's python installs (Blender has its own python requirements).  I got OSMX installed via Conda, but then Blender starting giving me all sorts of errors when using the Conda environment even following the suggestions on how to get Conda to work with Blender.

What I did is install all dependencies via pip, mindful of which version is the prereq as what is already installed may not be the version OSMX needs.

Then I installed OSMX via pip using a local wheel download from https://pypi.org/project/osmnx/#files (installing direct only had an old version and gave installation errors).

On Windows,

```
 .\python -m pip install osmnx-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

After installing the pre-reqs, the wheel installed with no errors.  If you have a dependency that isn't met - it will tell you and what specific version is needed.

In my case, while I had Shapely installed from another package, OSMX wanted 2.0 so I had to upgrade it using

```
.\python -m pip install shapely --upgrade
```

Hope this helps,

M

Answer (score 0):

Try install with conda:

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx
```

https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this, if you have installed `osmnx` using the above instructions , you will need to activate the environment each time you want to use it. To do this in anaconda prompt, type the following:

`conda activate ox`

This takes you from the `base` environment to the `ox` environment. You will then be able to execute the above code in anaconda prompt by typing

`python myprogram.py`

where `myprogram.py` is the name of your python program.

Older versions of `osmnx` installed into the base environment. However, this is not the case anymore it seems. I think there were some issues with package clashes or something.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to install osnmx without conda try these steps:

1. From the [OSMnx Github repo](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx) get the latest requirements.txt file
2. Install all requirements with `pip` command:
   `python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt`
3. Install osmnx with `pip` while all modules are satisfied:
   `python3 -m pip install osmnx`

Answer (score -1):

You can find the answer in [Installing OSMnx on Windows by Joshua Kobina Obeng](https://joshkobeng.medium.com/installing-osmnx-on-windows-cc96a3b432ea) article.

I will inlude the stesps as it is easy for you to see.

1. Open Anaconda command prompt(base) and type the following commands.

```html
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx
```

2. Then activate the enironment according to the instructions shown on the command prompt.
3. Open Anaconda Navigator.
4. In the "applications on" drop down, select "ox".
5. Instll Jupyter notebook by click on th  install button given under "Jupyter Notebook".
6. After instllation complleted, launch Jupyter Notebook.
7. Open notebook and import osmnx.